# a special java thread in dump file

Tags: java, jvm, dump, jstack

When my java application becomes unresponsive,i use `jstack -F`(if I run `jstack` without the `-F` flag it doesn't give me anything) command to dump the thread info,and there is a special thread in the dump file.

```
Thread 110175: (state = IN_VM)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.freeMemory(long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer$Deallocator.run() @bci=17, line=94 (Compiled frame)
 - sun.misc.Cleaner.clean() @bci=12, line=143 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.util.internal.Cleaner0.freeDirectBuffer(java.nio.ByteBuffer) @bci=34, line=66 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0.freeDirectBuffer(java.nio.ByteBuffer) @bci=1, line=147 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.freeDirectBuffer(java.nio.ByteBuffer) @bci=13, line=281 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.freeDirect(java.nio.ByteBuffer) @bci=1, line=115 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.buffer.UnpooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.deallocate() @bci=24, line=508 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release() @bci=39, line=106 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release(java.lang.Object) @bci=11, line=59 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.safeRelease(java.lang.Object) @bci=1, line=84 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.remove() @bci=40, line=258 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer.removeBytes(long) @bci=83, line=334 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doWrite(io.netty.channel.ChannelOutboundBuffer) @bci=238, line=301 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush0() @bci=89, line=716 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.flush0() @bci=9, line=303 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.flush() @bci=15, line=685 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.flush(io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext) @bci=4, line=1118 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeFlush() @bci=8, line=663 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1500(io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext) @bci=1, line=32 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$16.run() @bci=4, line=651 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(long) @bci=26, line=380 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run() @bci=106, line=357 (Compiled frame)
 - io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run() @bci=13, line=116 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)
```

After i use `jstack -F`,the application starts responding and goes on as if nothing had happened until it eventually stops responding again.

When the app is normal,i use `jstack -F` to search last thread,and it always `IN_NATIVE`.

Here are my questions.

1. Can this thread make my application unresponsive?
2. What is this thread?

Comment: That first question is not a question. That is a statement.

Comment: What is the status of this thread?

Comment: @Luminous,i am not sure the thread can make the application unresponsive.

Comment: @harshavmb,when application normally,the thread in dump file always `IN_NATIVE`,but when application has error,the status is 'IN_VM'

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the thread's stack trace, most of the calls are in the `io.netty` package.

The bottom two classes, SingleThreadEventExecutor and NioEventLoop, indicate in their Javadoc that they are general event dispatcher threads. So the code that code be running in them, could be any code. Presumably it is often running *your* code.

So to answer your questions

1. Yes, but only if it is running code that takes too long / uses too much CPU to handle events for your hardware configuration. That could be other code from the netty framework, or your code.
2. It's a general event dispatcher thread. It's not a special thread.

Comment: My code need often run the field.How to avoid the app no responding?

Answer (score 0):

This thread is invoking `sun.misc.Cleaner` to clean the direct memory (out of heap). May be the direct memory used to much to cost a long time to collect. You can use System.gc() to collect the direct mem periodically. And set `-XX:ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent` and use CMS collector to avoid the app no responding.

Comment: Here are my config,`-Xms32g -Xmx100g -XX:+UseParNewGC  -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly \
 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCCause -Xloggc:/var/log/flume-ng/gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M `,but after three days latter,it's error appeared again.

Comment: some places retained Netty bytebuf but not released?